# I want to add an element to my json key without " " at the start of my element

Tags: python, json

I want this result in my json :

```
"output":["element"]
```

what i am getting is :

```
"output":"[element]"
```

Here is my code:

```
x['output'] ="[element]"; // adding element to my x[output]

print(json.dumps(decoded, ensure_ascii=False)) // printing result in terminal
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the string `"[element]"`.  `["element"]` would be a list with one string in it.

`x['output'] = ["element"]`